# Can someone please tell me what the very bright star is that I see throughout the evening in the northern sky?

Tags: star

I'm located in NYC. I know it's not a planet, although it is very spherical and looks like one. Perhaps it's a satellite, because it doesn't move much and I don't recall ever seeing a star that appears so round.

Comment: Hi. It is a big sky :-). Can you provide more details such as the time, the direction (east? South? West? Domething in between, Etc) and angle above the horizon (0 degrees is oh the horizon, 90 degrees is straight overhead, 45 degrees is half way, etc.)

Comment: Are you looking thru a telescope or binocs?  How do you know it's round?  Naked-eye view of stars definitely does NOT yield round images.

Comment: Are you sure it's in the *northern* sky? Sirius is visible all night at the moment, and it is the brightest of all the stars we can see (other than the Sun).

Comment: Timing is key too. Venus and Jupiter are pretty bright at the right time

Comment: Satellites (at least those visible from the ground) move very fast across the sky.

Comment: I was looking at this because I wasn't sure between Venus and Jupiter https://earthsky.org/astronomy-essentials/visible-planets-tonight-mars-jupiter-venus-saturn-mercury